# Does the psql CLI client have an equivalent like .ssh/config to define host, user, password, database?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Having `.ssh/config` with an entry like this:

```
Host foo
  HostName 226.212.131.212
  User root
```

allows you to connect to a server using `ssh foo`.

Postgres' default client `psql` has the `.pgpass` file that allows to store a password. However, the client still needs to be instructed with parameters for host, username and dbname.

What I'm looking for is an equivalent to the ssh config - a way to access a postgres server using a named config. `psql foo`. Does it exist?

Comment: I don't think there's an option for psql, but the third party pgcli has an alias_dsn section for this sort of thing: https://www.pgcli.com/config

Comment: you can define a global variable connection string in your .bash_profile or in a file referenced in it, like foo="-h yourhost -d yourdb -p 5432 -U youruser"
and then psql $foo

Comment: you can use too the predefined global variables https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/libpq-envars.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one that is closest to that, is the [connection service file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgservice.html)

From the manual:

> The file uses an “INI file” format where the section name is the service name and the parameters are connection parameters;
>
> ```
> [foo]
> host=somehost
> port=5432
> user=arthur
> ```

Once the service is defined, you can connect using e.g.:

```
psql "service=foo"
```

Comment: Parameters 'dbname' and 'password' also exist

Answer (score 2):

To build on top of [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57279879/4683950),

For making it work make sure that your config file is saved to the correct location.
From the manual , the corrects paths are :

- `/etc/pg_service.conf`
- `~/.pg_service.conf`

Now if your file is saved to that location, you can now edit it make sure you have all the required settings.

```
[a_service]
 
host=host/orIP 
 
port=5432
 
dbname=xyz
 
user=paul
 
password=cde
```

You can add as many as you like, the same way we do with ssh_config

To use it, you can use it with the  following code:

You can do use it with two-step:

`export PGSERVICE=a_service`
and then run `psql`

Or in one command with :

```
psql "service=a_service"
```